# Automatically Enable Airplane Mode at Home?

Tags: airplane-mode

I have Project Fi and my data connection at home is spotty -- I often miss calls.  I would like to automatically enable airplane mode when I get home (by GPS probably?).  When I leave, I would like to disable airplane mode.

I have a Nexus 5X with beta 7.1.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: As far as I know, to switch airplane mode on/off needs root, using automation apps. Hence asked root status

Comment: @beeshyams I highly doubt it is rooted, since OP is running 7.1.1 **and** that is a beta. As far as we know, Nougat is going to be an absolute nightmare to root successfully.

Comment: @DanBrown: you are right. That was my thought too but just wanted to be doubly sure. Had aborted posting a solution half way :) Thanks

Comment: @beeshyams No problem!  I'm just going to experiment with this, see what I can find (maybe adb?)

Comment: @DanBrown: All the best. [Not going to be easy !!](http://betanews.com/2016/07/20/android-7-0-nougat-root/)

Comment: @beeshyams It may be possible without root, [Using a combination of Tasker, AutoInput, and possibly Secure settings](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/32j2h8/question_is_it_possible_on_lollipop_to_make/)

Comment: @DanBrown:: thanks. I am not familiar with any of those. ( I use Macrodroid ). But yes, theoretically it may be possible with *extreme* geeky ways but I do definitely recall reading that to toggle data you need root. I would rather *remember* to do something rather than do all these complex stuff. With Macrodroid, it is a simple pair of macros **if** you have root

Comment: @beeshyams True. The only issue here is you have to Pay for tasker (duh) AND the paid version of AutoInput. I don't have Gapps, so I can't even activate the trial

Comment: @DanBrown is correct -- my device is not rooted.

Comment: Daniel, my answer works around it. Also, tasker is worth it. Not advertising.

Comment: @beeshyams I've included an answer that does the job, and needs no root access.

Comment: Plus one :) let's see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Automation! Yay!

You are going to need four things:

- Tasker, either the [free trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/releases/Tasker.4.8u5.apk) which lasts 7 days, or the [full version on the play store](http://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)
- [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en_GB&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dautoinput&pcampaignid=APPU_1_rd0LWPj5L-mSgAbkiJiADg)
- [This script I made!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlhlqntlhapa75o/AirplaneToggle.prf.xml?dl=0)
- A few minutes to spare. **(At least you do not need root!)**

PREMINILARY. Install Tasker and AutoInput, and open them both at least once. Also, ensure you downloaded the script. Also, Go settings -> accessibility and grant access to both Tasker and AutoInput.

1. Go into tasker, and tap the house, then 'import' then the script I gave you (should be AirplaneToggle.prf.xml) to import it.
2. Close Tasker while connected to WiFi, and watch to see if it works. It should!

**What is that script doing?**

Simply put, the script starts up the wireless and networks settings, creates a fake tap to enable airplane mode, waits a little, then returns to your homescreen, and also disables tasker to finish.
Keep in mind:

- If you want to have this **only** apply to Home WiFi, you need to configure the WiFi bit. In tasker, tap the stuff on the **left** of the green arrow, and add the SSID (The name) of your WiFi hub. For example, I have a sky Hub, so it would be 'SKYXXXXX6' (X's replaced with random characters) that I put into the SSID field.
- This task disables Tasker when finished to avoid it looping constantly. You can re-enable it by holding your finger on the grey lightning cog in taskers main menu (top left) **OR** by adding a widget that let's you toggle it from the homescreen!*
- Delays are in place to allow for animations and Lag to finish safely. Also, the script will take you to your home screen when done.
- You can still enable your WiFi in airplane mode- just don't enable tasker when on your Home WiFi! (I already said that, right?)
- Tweak the task if you want. Not stopping you at all.
- Tasker is woring paying for, but free alternatives are available! (Or be an ass, and just trial Hop (backup the scripts before the trial expires, then uninstall and reinstall said trial version)

*Just found out there is no Widget to enable tasker. You will **have** to do it via opening Tasker itself.

*All links are legitimate, including the trial (it links to the official site, as a direct download) if you feel links are illegitimate, say so in the comments*